# Why does the compiler claim this class method has no return value?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, switch-statement

The error I get from Eclipse is "No return, in function returning non-void."  I added the default: case to see if it'd take away the error, but no beans.  I thought it'd be okay to return an rvalue because it'd be copied-by-value onto the stack and thus a copy of the string would exist when the local variables of getLogLevelName() go out of scope.  Indeed, the calling code works, but the error is mysterious to me.

```
std::string bmd2::Logger::getLogLevelName(bmd2::Logger::LogLevel logLevel) throw ()
{
  switch (logLevel)
  {
    case bmd2::Logger::LogLevel::LOG_ERROR:
      return std::string ("ERROR");
      break;
    case bmd2::Logger::LogLevel::LOG_WARNING:
      return std::string ("WARNING");
      break;
    case bmd2::Logger::LogLevel::LOG_INFO:
      return std::string ("INFO");
      break;
    case bmd2::Logger::LogLevel::LOG_DEBUG:
    default:
      return std::string ("DEBUG");
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: `std::string` has an implicit conversion constructor so you can just do `return "string text";` Since `std::string` is the return type one will automatically be created.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being explicit though

Comment: Get rid of all the unreachable break statements.

Comment: I thought it is an error tip of eclipse CDT, and it can be compiled by gcc or msvc.

Comment: Eclipse was not smart enough to handle the unnecessary break statements.  After I removed the breaks, eclipse was happy as a clam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse is reporting this as an error because whatever C++ analysis tool/library it's using is it not deducing that the `default` case in the switch-statement is effectively the end of the function. This should behave perfectly fine even though Eclipse says otherwise. Perhaps a better way to pacify Eclipse would be to put the default return statement after the switch statement.

```
std::string bmd2::Logger::getLogLevelName(bmd2::Logger::LogLevel logLevel) throw ()
{
  switch (logLevel)
  {
    case bmd2::Logger::LogLevel::LOG_ERROR:
      return std::string ("ERROR");
    case bmd2::Logger::LogLevel::LOG_WARNING:
      return std::string ("WARNING");
    case bmd2::Logger::LogLevel::LOG_INFO:
      return std::string ("INFO");
    case bmd2::Logger::LogLevel::LOG_DEBUG:
    default:
      // We will return the default value after the switch statement.
      break;
  }
  // Return default value.
  return std::string ("DEBUG");
}
```

Comment: Would removing all the break-after-the-return pacify eclipse? It seems silly to not like this construct since there is a "default" path, so I'd hope that something else was throwing it off .. like unnecessary breaks.

Comment: I doubt removing the `break` after the `return` in the switch would pacify Eclipse if it already doesn't detect the unavoidable `return` in the `case`s and `default`. But, the `break`s after the `returns` are redundant and it can't hurt to remove them.

Comment: @user2864740 According to @jakeliquorblues, when he removed the extra `break`s, Eclipse was happy.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because your compiler (Eclipse) can not see the `return`-statement in the `switch` scope. You can add

```
return std::string("CAN-BE-ANY-THING");  // this line will never be called though
```

at the end of the function to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it's perfectly legal to write a function which is declared to return a value but never actually does. A problem occurs only if execution at runtime actually returns from such a function without returning a value.

```
// this program is perfectly legal and well behaved; just don't ever call foo()
int foo() {}

int main() { return 0; }
```

But programmers want compilers to help them produce correct and well behaved programs, and so compilers try to figure out when a program could possibly do bad things and tell the programmer about them. The problem is that C++ defines 'bad things' such that perfectly figuring out at compile time if they really can happen requires, for example, solving the halting problem.

Obviously a compiler isn't going to do that, so in trying to help the programmer sometimes the compiler is going to get things wrong. Hopefully the compiler handles most cases of real code well most of the time, but there will inevitably be cases the compiler doesn't handle and which therefore result in a false positive (where the compiler warns of a problem that can't really happen) or false negative (where the compiler fails to warn about a problem that can happen).

You have two basic choices: Either tell the compiler to stop trying to help you in the particular way that produces this message (by disabling this warning), or you can change the code so that the compiler's not-quite-correct analysis is still able to figure out that it always returns a value.

---

Languages other than C++ have taken other approaches, such as simply making it illegal to fail to return a value in such a way that a simple analysis can see the return. C#, for example, takes that route explicitly so that the compiler can check it and be completely correct.